# Store multiple XML files in Android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am developing a survey android app so that:

- Each survey is downloaded from server as XML file.
- A survey can have multiple versions (new survey, new XML).
- When a new XML is downloaded it should overwrite its corresponding
  previous XML.

I would like to store the files in a sqlite database. How can I insert my files into the db?

Should I use BLOB or store the content of the XML as string? In any case how should I do it?

Comment: please note that sqlite doesn't really respect the type anyway...

Comment: Have you tried something that isn't working for you?

Comment: I am aware that Data type integrity is not maintained in SQLite, for now I'm storing files in sd card, but i want to move them to the db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the whole xml string as a standard string in the database. Then you can retrieve it and parse it easily.

For tutorials on using sqlite in android refer:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/06/simple-example-using-androids-sqlite_02.html